# How can I properly format different "sub" .tex files to include them with the \input{Chapters} command?

Tags: sectioning

I am a total latex beginner and I am having trouble understanding how to properly include and structure sections with the `\input{chapter}` command. I have been using this tutorial from overleaf ([LINK](https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_Write_a_Thesis_in_LaTeX_(Part_1)%3A_Basic_Structure)). The tuturial suggests using seperate .tex files for all of the main-body chapters and then including them using the `\input{chapter}` command. The chapters I have created look like this:

[image]

To include the chapters, I use the: `\chapter{Theory}  \input{Chapters/Theory}` command. But how do I structure these "sub" .tex files? For example, within the Theory.tex file, I tried something simple to see what it looks like:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{section}
        \blindtext
    \end{section}
\end{document}
```

I included it using the `\chapter{Theory}  \input{Chapters/Theory}` command. However, on the main.tex page it looks like this when I compile it:

[image]

How do I properly structure these "sub" .tex files, so when I include them, it doesn't look like everything is in the title?

Comment: It's very simple, really: `\input` takes the file in your command and adds it to your main file, just like you had typed it there yourself. So there's no need to repeat a preamble, etc.

Comment: @Ingmar Do I need to make a seperate .tex file for every subsection then? For example, let's say I have Chapter 3.1, Chapter 3.2 etc. Will I need to make Chapter31.tex, Chapter32.tex etc.? I guess I just don't see the point of separating the main.tex files and including other .tex files for the main chapters. What's the advantage?

Comment: Say your document has a few hundred pages and the first 5 of 20 Chapters are finished. You can speed up compiling time by including only the chapters you are working on. Another advantage is, that only opening required parts reduces RAM needed; today thats probably obsolete.

Comment: you don't need to use `\input` at all, you can have all your sections and chapters in one file, it makes no difference to latex, splitting parts to separate files is just a convenience for editing, especially if different people  are editing different parts. the lack of section title is unrelated to `\input` you just have the wrong syntax it should be `\section{section title}` the same as `\chapter{chapater title}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah I see. The ``` \section{section title}``` was where it was all going wrong. I was able to fix it with your help. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first remove begin/end document in the included file, that'll raise an error (best case) or the main file ends after the included \end{document}.

I didn't know there was a section-Environment - the LaTeX tutorials (and Point-and-Click-Editors) I know of use \section{bla} to create a knew section (titled "bla").

Your Theory.tex should therefore look like:

```
\section{first} \blindtext
\section{second} \blindtext
...
```

Comment: You answer and David Carlisles comment fixed it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the only sensible option to format different "sub" .tex files is to not use `\input{...}` at all, but rather use the `subfiles` package.

Depending on the size of the document and the length of the chapters, I would suggest using a separate document for each chapter. Assuming the following folder structure:

```
project folder
 |-- main.tex
 |-- chapters
      |- chap1.tex
      |- chap2.tex
      |- ...
 |- ...
```

Your `main.tex` would look something like this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{subfiles}

% other packages

\begin{document}

\subfile{chapters/chap1.tex}
\subfile{chapters/chap2.tex}
% ...

\end{document}
```

And each chapter would contain only the following content (e.g. for `chap1.tex`):

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
% some text

\end{document}
```

The main advantage over `\input` is the possibility to compile all files individually without modifying anything. You only have one preamble for all files (the one in `main.tex`). More about this in the [manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfiles).